# Performing double letter swap operations

Tags: python, string

I want to change the letters in my input. To do this I have implemented a dictionary that works for a singular letter. However, I want to have a different output if there is a "double-letter". For example, `"text"` should be returned with `"rexr"`, which it does. But for `"textt"`, I would want it to return `"rexss"`. Below is the attached code. Any tips?

```py
vowels = {
    "t" : "r",
    "r" : "s",
    "s" : "b",
    "b" : "t",
    "T" : "R",
    "R" : "S",
    "S" : "B",
    "B" : "T",
    "tt" : "ss",
    "rr" : "bb",
    "ss" : "rr",
    "bb" : "tt",
    "TT" : "SS",
    "RR" : "BB",
    "SS" : "TT",
    "BB" : "RR"
}

inputString = input()

outputString = ""

for character in inputString:

    if character in vowels: 
        outputString += vowels[character]
    else:
        outputString += character

print(outputString)
```

Comment: dont use string concattenation - this is creating and destroying plenty of unmutable strings in the process. use a list as intermeridate thing and `"".join( ["a","b","c"])`

Comment: What is the expected output for "texttt"?

Comment: @Fractal FWIW, I assume `"rexssr"`

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regex for that. Ensure you craft the regex starting with the longest strings so that 'tt' matches before 't':

```py
inputString = 'text textt'

import re

regex = '|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(vowels, key=len, reverse=True)))
# 'tt|rr|ss|bb|TT|RR|SS|BB|t|r|s|b|T|R|S|B'

re.sub(regex, lambda x: vowels.get(x.group()), inputString)
```

output: `'rexr rexss'`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to incrementally construct the result, you can use a `while` loop with string slicing. A `for` loop wouldn't easily work here, because you don't know how many characters to skip over for each iteration.

```py
user_input = input()
result_characters = []

idx = 0
while idx != len(user_input):
    if user_input[idx:idx + 2] in vowels:
        result_characters.append(vowels[user_input[idx:idx + 2]])
        idx += 2
    else:
        result_characters.append(vowels.get(user_input[idx], user_input[idx]))
        idx += 1

print(''.join(result_characters))
```

Comment: I wondered if it was possible to allow arbitrary-length keys in `vowels`, as well as eliminate the magic constants, and [it turns out it is, but the code's pretty complicated](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/8bf6109c136ceb73ee650341895be991). I'd rather use [mozway's regex solution](/a/71742633/4518341) in that case; I think it's equivalent, but much simpler.